# Rate of decrease of a function

Tags: functions, derivatives

Given the function
$$f(x)=-x^3+15x^2$$
I have to find out its rate of decrease. I know
$$f'(x)=-3x^2+30x$$
which give me $x=0$ its minimum local. But can I say its rate of decrease is equal to zero? It doesn't make so much sense for me.

Comment: Rate of decrease at a particular value of $x$? Rate of decrease as a function of $x$? Why do you need to "find out its rate of decrease"? If this is an exercise from a book, maybe seeing the original wording would help.